# How to count same names in a Data Structure?

Tags: java

I need to count the same names of students in Binary Search Tree and Singly linked list. But i couldn't find how to do that. Does someone have answer for it?

```
public class Student  {

   private int ID;
   private String name;
   private String surname;

   public Student(int id, String n, String s)
   {
      ID = id;
      name = n;
      surname = s;
   }

   public int getID() 
   {
      return ID;
   }

   public String getName() 
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String getSurname()
   {
      return surname;      
   }

   public void setID(int newID) 
   { 
      ID = newID; 
   }

   public void setName(String newName) 
   { 
      name = newName; 
   }

   public void setSurname(String newSurname)
   {
      surname = newSurname;
   }

   public String ToString()
   {
      return "\nname : "+name+"\nsurname : "+surname+"\nid : "+ID+"\n"; 
   }
}
```

Student class above

```
public class NodeBST 
{
   private Student s;
   private NodeBST left;
   private NodeBST right;
   private int index ;

   public NodeBST(Student newS) 
   {
      s = newS;
      left = null;
      right = null;
      index = 0 ;
   }

   public int getIndex(){
      return index ;
   }

   public Student getStudent() 
   { 
      return s;
   }

   public NodeBST getLeft() 
   {
      return left; 
   }

   public NodeBST getRight() 
   {
      return right; 
   }

   public void setIndex(int idx){
      index = idx ;
   }

   public void setStudent(Student newS) 
   { 
      s = newS; 
   }

   public void setLeft(NodeBST newLeft) 
   {
      left = newLeft; 
   }

   public void setRight(NodeBST newRight) 
   {
      right = newRight; 
   }

   public boolean hasLeft() 
   {
       return (left != null);
   }

   public boolean hasRight() 
   {
       return (right != null);
   }
}
```

node class for binary search tree above

```
import java.util.*;
public class BST 
{
   private NodeBST root;   
   int size ;
   String[] names ;

   public BST() 
   {
      names = new String[50];
      root = null;
      size = 0 ;
   }

   public BST(NodeBST newNodeBST) 
   {
      root = newNodeBST;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() 
   {
      return (root == null);
   }

   public void insert(NodeBST newNodeBST) 
   {
      if(isEmpty())
      { // root is null
         root = newNodeBST;
         root.setIndex(size);
         names[size] = root.getStudent().getName() ;
         size++;
      }
      else
      {
         NodeBST tempNodeBST = root;
         while(true)
         {
            if(newNodeBST.getStudent().getID() < tempNodeBST.getStudent().getID())
            {
               if(tempNodeBST.getLeft() == null)
               {
                  tempNodeBST.setLeft(newNodeBST);
                  tempNodeBST.getLeft().setIndex(size);
                  size++;
                  break;
               }   
               else
                  tempNodeBST = tempNodeBST.getLeft();
            }
            else
            {
               if(tempNodeBST.getRight() == null)
               {
                  tempNodeBST.setRight(newNodeBST);
                  tempNodeBST.getRight().setIndex(size);
                  size++;
                  break;
               }   
               else
                  tempNodeBST = tempNodeBST.getRight();
            }
        }   
    }
```

There is a method to insert student in binary search three. So how can i count the same names in this binary search tree. In below how i tried to do that but it didn't work.

```
    public void nameCounter(){
    String [] tempNames = names ;
    for(int element = 0 ; element < size ; element++){
        int contains = 1 ;
        for(int counter = element ; counter < size ; counter++){
            if(tempNames[element].equals(tempNames[counter]) && element != counter)        { 
               contains++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tempNames[element] +" : "+contains);
    }
}
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: What is the simplest example which has a problem, and what do you see when you step through the code in your debugger when you try to debug your program?

Comment: when i add 4 same names in binary search tree, it looks like this: asil : 4
asil : 3
asil : 3
asil : 3 @peterLawrey

Comment: Can you include a test you wrote to reproduce this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the array in your tree? Is it for debugging purposes only? What do you see if you ignore the array and just look at the nodes in your tree?